# A brand new repo with eGIT/bitbucket

Tags: repository, push, egit

I use eGIT within the Eclipse environment, now trying to push a brand new repo to bitbucket. The repo needs to be initialized first at bitbucket remote server before the push, Is there any possibility to start the new repo from eGIT itself with no remote repo?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check the below tutorials about creating new git repo from eclips:
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html#create-a-new-git-repository-via-eclipse